# How to create the "right" TypeScript .d.ts?

Tags: typescript

Project -

```
[my-lib]
/
 src/
    /A.ts
    /B.ts
```

Generator [dts-generator](https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator) `index.d.ts` follows -

```
declare module "my-lib/A" {
    export class A{}
}

declare module "my-lib/B" {
    import A from "my-lib/A";
    export class B{}
}

declare module "my-lib" {
}
```

This Declaration works, but causes some discomfort when auto import in the `ide` and when loading `systemjs`.  So the question is - how to generate Declaration them to be like everyone else? How to generate a .d.ts like below?

```
declare module MyLib {
    export class A{}
    export class B{}
}

declare module "my-lib" {
    export = MyLib;
}
```

Or maybe there's a way to tell the compiler to Declaration merged into a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe there's a way to tell the compiler to Declaration merged into a single file

No.

> This Declaration works

This is the the true runtime definition. The one you are trying to push i.e.

```
declare module MyLib {
    export class A{}
    export class B{}
}

declare module "my-lib" {
    export = MyLib;
}
```

Is **invalid** as from your folder structure importing `my-lib` will give you module not resolved error at runtime